# Why is $\Big\{\frac{1}{n^2}\Big\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup \hspace{0.2cm} \{-1,0 \}$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We have a set on Real numbers:

$$\Big\{\frac{1}{n^2}\Big\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup \hspace{0.2cm}\{-1,0 \}$$

I can't seem to understand why this is a compact set as if we look at the interval I think that there are tiny spaces in between the points of this interval that aren't in it. Isn't it so that a compact set must contain it's points and be somehow continuous?

Does that mean even let's say for example: $A = \{{1,2,3}\}$ that only contains this points is compact? Am I missing something here?

Comment: All points, except for $0$ are isolated points. But $0$ is the limit point of $1/n^2$. So the set is closed. The boundedness is trivial

Comment: The set $A$ you give is compact and no, a compact set doesn't have to be "continuous". What definition of compact are you using?

Comment: Looks like I didn't completely understand the part that a compact set can be many isolated points. I think I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that points of $\Bbb R$ are compact. Therefore the subset $\{-1\}$ is compact. Now $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = 0$, therfore $0$ is a limit point of the set $S = \{\frac{1}{n^2}: n \in \Bbb N\}$. Now if $x$ is a limit point of $S$, then there is a subsequence of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ which converges to $x$. But this forces $x = 0$. Therefore $0$ is the only limit point of $S$. Therefore $S\cup \{0$} is closed. Since it is trivially bounded, $S\cup \{0\}$ is compact(Heine Borel Theorem). Therefore $S\cup \{0\}\cup\{-1\}$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Call the subset $X$ and consider an open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$. There must be an open set $V_{-1}\in\mathcal U$ containing $-1$ and an open set $V_0\in\mathcal U$ containing $0$. For such $V_0$ there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\subseteq V_0$ and therefore $n^{-2}\in V_0$ for all $n>\varepsilon^{-1/2}$. Now we only need open subsets $V_1,\cdots, V_{\left\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1/2}\right\rfloor}\in \mathcal U$ such that $k^{-2}\in V_k$ for all $1\le k\le\left\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1/2}\right\rfloor$, which we have.

$\left\{V_i\,:\, -1\le i\le \left\lfloor\varepsilon^{-1/2}\right\rfloor\right\}$ is a cover of $X$ by at most $\left\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1/2}\right\rfloor+2$ elements of $\mathcal U$.

Answer (score 2):

The first part has been answered above. For your second part of the question:

If by "continuous" you mean without gaps in the infinitesimal sense, then no. **Any** finite set in **any** topological space is compact. So give $\mathbb{R}$ any topology you want, and the set $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ is still compact.